# Why does my && concatenated comparison return different results?

Tags: c#, .net

Can somebody explain why the comparison without brackets `result1 == true` returns a different result than the comparison with brackets `result2 == false`? Both results should be false because `_enum != TestEnum.Member2`.

```
class Program
{
    private static TestEnum _enum = TestEnum.Member1;
    private static int? _int = null;
    private static string _string = null;

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var result1 = _enum == TestEnum.Member2 &&
                      _int != null ? _int == 5 : true &&
                      _string != null ? _string == "abc" : true;
        var result2 = (_enum == TestEnum.Member2) &&
                      (_int != null ? _int == 5 : true) &&
                      (_string != null ? _string == "abc" : true);

        Console.WriteLine("result1: " + result1);
        Console.WriteLine("result2: " + result2);
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    Member1,
    Member2
}
```

.net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/daA0Lh

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170) `&&` is done before `? :`

Comment: @phuzi thank you for the link, but i still don't get it, according to the link the second operand should only be evaluated if the first one returns true.

Comment: If you visualize the operator precedence in practice, the calculation of `result1` looks like this: `(_enum == TestEnum.Member2 && _int != null) ? _int == 5 : (true && _string != null) ? _string == "abc" : true;`. Evaluating the statements inside each `( )` leaves you with: `(false) ? _int == 5 : (true && false --> false) ? _string == "abc" : true;`.

Comment: As an aside, this is a really good argument against mixing multiple `? :` operators in a single expression. It quickly gets needlessly confusing. Always consider simplifying such statements, and where this is not possible, just use multiple `if`s or `switch`es. The tax on lines should be far less than the tax on maintainability. There are many ways to rewrite this; recent versions of C# would allow `(_enum, _int, _string) is (TestEnum.Member2, 5 or null, "abc" or null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is operator precedence

This is the order of precedence for the operators that you're using.

1. `()`
2. `==`
3. `&&`
4. `? :`

So...

```
var result1 = _enum == TestEnum.Member2 &&
                      _int != null ? _int == 5 : true &&
                      _string != null ? _string == "abc" : true;
```

Is the same as - the parentheses here should *not* alter the how the expression is evaluated, but should serve to make it clear how the expression is being evaluated.

```
var result1 = ((_enum == TestEnum.Member2) && _int != null)
       ? (_int == 5)
       : ((true && _string != null)
          ? _string == "abc"
           : true);
```